# Terrible Watson transcription

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm trying to use Watson to create the transcription of an audio file in brasilian portuguese. I made the call to the api and the result returned successfully. But the transcription is beyond terrible. It's absolutely useless, with no word being recognized correctly.
I used the following command:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:<key>" --header "Content-Type: audio/mp3" --data-binary @./file.mp3 
"https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/<code>/v1/recognize/model=pt-BR_BroadbandModel"
```

The test audio consists in a 9 min part of a 90 mins audio. It's an interview of a resercher with a dockworker. It has been recorded with a cel phone. I have upload it here, for examination: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xuibxksudp55uwaz6oSOccTZ3pP7Dya9/view?usp=sharing

It's not possible that Watson has a so terrible transcription. What am I missing ? do I have to set some parameter or do some work in the audio first ?

I tried the narrowband model also. Tried flac also.

Comment: Did you try using another model?

Comment: Did you train an acoustic model or domain dictionary? Those greatly increase the accuracy out of the box. Pre-processing your audio to clean it up will also help.

Comment: There are only 2 models for portuguese language. I tried both.

Comment: Did not train acoustic model. After the holidays I'll try to do that and also improve  audio. Any recomendations on how to improve audio?

Answer (score -1):

the watson ibm api seems not to be properly codd for end users, the reasons seem their api design is overcomplicated for transcriptions.
it has a bug I believe their team has not been able to decode

It is however advisable to work with google
and speechRecognition

```
    pip install --upgrade SpeechRecognition(linux, unix systems)
or  C:\path_to_ python.exe -m pip install --upgrade SpeechRecognition (windows)
```

this is one module that has all the built in
capacity for the different api creators such as ibm
google, microsoft etc,
just by using

```
import speech_recogntion as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile("path to audio file") as source:
       #r.adjust_for_ambient_noise() depending on if you have background noise 
      audio = r.record(source)
```

then ;
 recognize the file out put
 where xxx is the api creator from a list. say

```
  google, ibm, azure or bing(with microsoft)
  t = r.recognize_xxx(audio, credentials, ...)
```

read up more on the module to be more precise
this is only a rough guide